# Swing components freezed because of few methods

Tags: java, swing, freeze

I am facing a problem with a Java Swing based application that I have created for professional purpose.

A new class `PanelUserInput` and I have created a separate listener for this class called `PanelUserInputListener` which IS-A ItemListener and ActionListener.

The class `PanelUserInput` class has at least 5 Labels and ComboBoxes which have dummy values in them for now. There is also a Button to submit the selected values. I am using GridBadLayout for positioning the components.

Now the problem is that the selection of items in ComboBoxes is blocked via mouse. Though I can access the elements using my keyboard arrow keys(up and down).
Also, I am not able to click the Button using mouse but I can do so using my keyboard by only pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>

Has anybody seen this kind of behavior in Java Swing, and what is the optimum solution?

I would not be able to share the code because of confidentiality reasons.

Comment: *"I would not be able to share the code because of confidentiality reasons."*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Are you using a glass pane? Possibly with a mouse listener attached?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you always use the pattern

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
```

When responding to user action events. Not much more I can say without specifics.

Comment: *"Make sure you always use the pattern.."*  Seems overkill if `doSomething();` equates to `label.setText("You chose: Tomato!");` & it is already called on the EDT in response to an action or item event.

Comment: Should still do it in my opinion in case someone starts adding stuff to that code block.

Comment: Interesting point, that is cautious 'planning for the future' coding.  You've turned me around on it.  Thanks! :)

Comment: flamewar == disagree with doSomething() as global method, only in the case that if doSomething() is only one method from rellated Swing API, not method to build output to Swing GUI, then caused freeze as is described in OPs question, invokeLater is only programaticall delaying with output to EDT,